# Randomly generating a simple math equation, Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm using android studio to create an app that generates a random equation and the user will input an answer to the randomly generated equation and solve simple 2 digit addition and subtraction, and 1 digit division and multiplication. My problem is I'm unsure what i need to use to generate the random numbers for even a simple add and subtract method. Do i use something similar to

```
Random rand1 = new Random();
int operation1 = rand1.nextInt(100);
Random rand2 = new Random();
int operation2 = rand2.nextInt(100);
int sum = operation1 + operation2;
```

I feel as though I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with what you have. You only need one Random object for all numbers, though

Answer (score 0):

One instance of Random should be good for multiple callings of randomization. Depending on what you will need down the line regarding specific output and such will require you to utilize different Random method implementations. You're not over-complicating anything aside from that.